# How can I change the volume of a local notification in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, alarm

I'm developing an alarm clock for iOS. Anyone who's familiar with such an endeavor will know that the main problem is the lack of ability to launch your app from a background state. So, if it's not kept constantly open, you only have a Local Notification to fall back on, which means only using predefined sounds in the app bundle, which play for at most 30 seconds, and no control over the volume and silence switch (or Do Not Disturb mode).

However, I came across a cool alarm app, "Rocket Alarm", which was able to do one thing I thought was impossible: when it's in the background, and the notification pops up, it will change the volume, override the silence switch, and keep playing its music even after the notification is dismissed.

My question is simple: anyone know how they did it? (Maybe even someone from Timeline Inc., the developers of Rocket Alarm...)

Thanks!

Comment: they are just playing sound with AVAudioPlayer volume

Comment: But how can you run that code when a notification fires? Your app is in the background.

Comment: you can keep tasks in background all the time like this app, but apple probably will reject it

Comment: You can run code in the background in one of a select set of modes (audio playback, location tracking, newsstand updates, bluetooth or external accessory communications...), but an alarm doesn't meet any of these. Are you saying they are using a mode that should have been rejected?

Comment: yes there is no other magic there